# Erro de GetEnumerator ao renderizar uma View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Fiz isso apenas como um teste:

```
@model Operador.MVC.Models.OperadorModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Operador";
}

<table id="tblOperador" class="table table-hover table-striped" border="1" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>NameHealth</th>   
        <th>NameDental</th>
        <th>LastUpdateDate</th>  
        <th>LastUpdateLogin</th>     
        <th>Brand Code</th>    
        <th>Brand</th>         
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NameHealth)
        </td>                                             
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.NameDental, new { style = "width: 50px;"})
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</tbody>
```

Quando eu renderizo me dá esse erro:

> Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/'.
>
> Erro de Compilação
>
> Descrição: Erro ao compilar um recurso necessário para atender esta
>   solicitação. Examine os detalhes específicos do erro e modifique o
>   código fonte apropriadamente.
>
> Mensagem de Erro do Compilador: CS1579: Instrução foreach não pode
>   operar em variáveis do tipo 'Operador.MVC.Models.OperadorModel' porque
>   'Operador.MVC.Models.OperadorModel' não contém uma definição pública
>   para 'GetEnumerator'
>
> Erro de Origem:
>
> Linha 20:  Linha 21:  Linha 22: @foreach (var item in
>   Model) Linha 23: { Linha 24:
>
> Arquivo de Origem:
>   c:\Projetos_MVC\Operador.MVC\Views\Operador\Operador.cshtml    Linha:
>   22
>
> Mostrar Saída Detalhada do Compilador:
>
> Mostrar Origem de Compilação Completa:
>
> Informações sobre a Versão: Microsoft .NET Framework Versão:4.0.30319;
>   Versão do ASP.NET:4.0.30319.34249

Como eu faço para resolver o problema do GetEnumerator? O que eu devo adicionar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como o próprio erro diz:

> Instrução foreach não pode operar em variáveis do tipo 'Operador.MVC.Models.OperadorModel'

Seu erro está aqui:

```
foreach (var item in Model)
```

`Model` é uma variável do tipo `Operador.MVC.Models.OperadorModel` e você só pode fazer `foreach` em variáveis que implementem [`GetEnumerator()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator(v=vs.110).aspx), tais como `IEnumerable`, `List` e afins.

Comment: Já entendi, apenas para confirmar. Se eu tenho uma classe, digamos OperadorModelTeste e nela eu tenho um método que me retorna uma lista de operadores e se eu colocar assim: @model Operador.MVC.Models.OperadorModelTeste, dessa forma eu consigo fazer um foreach e preencher as TD's de minha table?

Comment: Não. Você tem que usar o método que retorna uma lista.

Comment: Mas como eu faço isso? Não entendi, me desculpe pela minha ignorância, mas não entendi como eu faço.